# Ignoring outputs in Cascading

Tags: filtering, logfile, cascading-deletes, cascading

I am analyzing log files with various domain names. I want to exclude/ignore from the output report any domain that has the word "macys". Here is an example output:

```
l.macys.com        87516
www.google.com     3016
search.yahoo.com   584
www.bing.com       166
macys-L0135874392.htm   1
```

I would like to have and output file were I would not see any domains with the word "macys".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a Cascading [`Filter`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/operation/Filter.html)

You would set this up with a [`RegexFilter`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/operation/regex/RegexFilter.html):

```
Pipe pipe = new Pipe(incomingPipe, new Fields("UrlColumn"), 
     new RegexFilter(".*macys.*", true), Fields.All);
```

Tailor the regex to your matching use case. The one above would remove all tuples (rows) that contain the word "macys"